# Enable Confluence to run on Port 80 in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, iis, azure, windows-server-2012, confluence

I am having difficulty getting Confluence running on windows server 2012 on port 80. (the machine in hosted in Azure which is why I need to run it on port 80 (i dont have access to other ports from where I am trying to use this)).

I believe something must be running on port 80 , though i did a netstat -y and didnt see anything.

I think its IIS any idea how I should kill that or what else could be causing confluence to not run on port 80?

*confluence works find on say port 8090 but i need to run it on port 80.

**mind you I cant get confluence to run on port 80 on the local instance of windows server, never mind accessing it from another location thus i dont think this has anything to do with azure**

running a 
    netstat -abn
shows nothing running on port 80. Im still not sure why I cant get confluence to work locally on port 80.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual machine in Azure is not directly public accessible. You need to configure endpoints in the cloudservice (which acts as a loadbalancer).

So for instance you can configure a public endpoint port 80 on the cloudservice to point to your VM port 8090. See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/ for more information.

[image: endpoint config example]

Comment: oh i think i understand what your saying, so have confluence run on its default port which works well (8090), then make it so port 80 redirects to 8090) and it should work?

Comment: this doesnt work because i cant get confluence to run locally on that machine

Answer (score 0):

If the Endpoint is open on Azure to the VM then my advice would be to check the firewall settings on the host.  Typically most ports are shut unless they are explicitly opened by installing a feature like IIS (windows web server).